# How can i update django foreignkey?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model `OrderItem` and it has a foreignkey `order`. I also have a function that creates an OrderItem like so,

```
OrderItem.objects.create(shopping_id=_shopping_id(request),
                                          quantity=quantity,
                                          item=i,
                                          created_by=anon_user,
                                          modified_by=anon_user)
```

As you can see i have not included `order` because i have failed to understand  how i can be able to do it.
i get the error `order_items.order_id may not be NULL`

here is my model `OrderItem`

```
class OrderItem(SmartModel):
    shopping_id = models.CharField(max_length=50,db_index=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order)
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if it exist if no create it and then create OrderItem object.
Code should look like this:

```
     try:
         order = Order.objects.get(pk=order_id)
     except:
           order = Order.objects.create(name=name)

     OrderItem.objects.create(shopping_id=_shopping_id(request),
                                      quantity=quantity,
                                      item=i,
                                      order=order
                                      created_by=anon_user,
                                      modified_by=anon_user)
```

Comment: oh, i cant down vote yet..thts why i think...but thnks once again

Answer (score 1):

Why is adding `order` any different from adding `item`? They're both ForeignKeys, and in both cases you simply pass the relevant object as the keyword argument.

Comment: 404 returned because of url or object not found. Are you sure that order object exist before add it to the OrderItem?

Comment: As wrote Daniel order and item object should be added on same way.

Comment: @UnLiMiTeD your right, `order object` does not exist before i add it to `OrderItem`, what do you advice i should here..

Answer (score 0):

Does this not work?

```
order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(...)
```

then

```
OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, shopping_id=_shopping_id(request),
                                          quantity=quantity,
                                          item=i,
                                          created_by=anon_user,
                                          modified_by=anon_user)
```

Comment: this would have worked in some other case but in my case it didn't, but thank you..