# How do i define fields when creating an object?

Tags: python, django

I am creating an object like so,

```
order = Order.objects.create(created_by=anon_user,modified_by=anon_user)
```

i am getting an error `orders_order.phone may not be NULL`. `phone` is one of many fields that belong to the `Order` model.

i have failed(logically) to include the `phone` field as i create the `Order` object.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Include the field when you create the object.

Comment: Use same logic like the question what I have been already answered for you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899334/how-can-i-update-django-foreignkey/14901251#14901251

Comment: If you dont want to pass phone object in the Order model allow null for it.

Comment: Alternatively, set those fields to blank and enforce their presence with a ModelForm if necessary.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams that is what i want help with, because i have tried `order = Order.objects.create(created_by=anon_user,modified_by=anon_user,phone=phone)`and it has failed.Maybe i just do not know how..

Comment: That's not what your question shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django requires your phone field to not be null right now. This also means you can't pass phone=None, so if your phone variable that you're passing into your Order object is None, it will fail.

Your options are:

1. Set a default value on the model
2. Allow null on the model
3. Pass in a non-null value to the model upon creation

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from your question the model requires that phone number be there on creation.

Things you can do.

1. `phone_number = models.PhoneField(null=True, blank=True)`
2. `phone_number = models.PhoneField(default='6132760547')`

Those to model changes should help first is saying that the field can be blank as in contain an `empty` or `None`

Second is if nothing is passed default value is that number.

Comment: ', i had fixed the problem by the time you posted your answer, i went with the first second option.